# Getting Intel SR-IOV Virtual Function counters

Tags: kvm-virtualization, linux-networking, libvirt, performance-counters, sr-iov

After some research on **Intel** **SR-IOV,** I've realized that there is no convenient way to get the **VF** counters while **VF** interface is being attached to a **VM** (for example to a **QEMU/KVM** VM with a **Libvirt** manager). Furthermore, I didn't find even an inconvenient way to do it, because as soon as **VM** is being created on a **HOST** and it is bound in configuration to some **VF** interface(this is the main use case of SRI-OV VFs), the interface is automatically being detached from the **HOST** and attached to the **VM** (I think that it is done on purpose in order to allow passthrough to bypass the kernel or something), and there is actually no way that I found yet to find the counters of the **VF** used by the attached **VM** on the **HOST**(I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I've tried looking for counters on VF ports, with `ethtool -S` on the PF interface but with no avail), those counters may be actually very helpful in various situations. It would be really helpful if someone who has some experience in dealing with **SRIOV** could shade some light on this issue and tell me I'm wrong and that there is a simple way.
Thanks!

**Update**:. 
Actually I found that `ethtool -S` might be useful, it let you see the **TX/RX** queue counters of the nic, and I found that **VF** function driver ixgbevf uses exactly one different pair of **TX/RX** queues for each **VF**. And they are being assigned in increasing order, so it might be possible to do a mapping. But unfortunately it's an ugly and driver dependent solution.

Comment: Why people downvote posts without any explanation..

Comment: They don't know the words you'e using :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you're not wrong,  the whole idea of SR-IOV is that it allows the VM to interact directly with the NIC without the hypervisor or host in the middle.  It isn't seeing the packets to generate counters,you won't get anything using ethtool or the normal ways. You maybe able to get something from the root of the NIC but it depends on the drivers your using etc.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought.. I'm using 82599 Intel nic, that uses ixgbe driver for PF and ixgbevf for VF. I saw the driver implementation in C++ and I saw that metrics are being collected in ixgbevf but are not reported.

Comment: I've added a possible temporary workaround.

Comment: Did you compare PCI pass thru Vs SR-IOV performance?

Comment: Actually SR-IOV uses pass-through for each mapping between Virtual Function and a VM(Guest).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this solution on Ubuntu, running  on a SRIOV enabled compute in openstack installation.
Steps to get counters for individual VF of a PF.
The physical NIC (25G) is running on INTEL i40 driver for XXV710 device.

```
#lspci |grep -i ethernet
 3b:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller XXV710 for 25GbE SFP28 (rev 02)
.....
# ethtool -i eth2
driver: i40e
version: 2.7.29
firmware-version: 7.20 0x80009f02 1.2829.0
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:3b:00.1
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

Step 1-

find for sriov dir in /sys/devices:

```
# find  /sys/devices/ -type d -name sriov 

/sys/devices/pci0000:3a/0000:3a:00.0/0000:3b:00.1/sriov
```

Step 2 : Go to this dir and do ls -lrt. You will see the VF numbers. These numbers are same as seen in output of "ip link show ' command. Do the corelation.

```
# find  /sys/devices/ -type d -name sriov  |xargs ls -lrt

/sys/devices/pci0000:3a/0000:3a:00.0/0000:3b:00.1/sriov:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Jan  9 21:40 7
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Jan  9 21:40 15
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Jan  9 21:40 5
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Jan  9 21:40 13
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Jan  9 21:40 3
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Jan  9 21:40 11
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Jan  9 21:40 1
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Jan  9 21:40 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Jan  9 21:40 6
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Jan  9 21:40 14
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Jan  9 21:40 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Jan  9 21:40 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Jan  9 21:40 2
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Jan  9 21:40 10
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Jan  9 21:40 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Jan  9 21:40 9
```

output of ip link show

```
## ip link show eth2
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq portid 3cfdfea85df9 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:fd:fe:a8:5d:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    vf 0 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off
    vf 1 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off
    vf 2 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off
    vf 3 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off
    vf 4 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off
    vf 5 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off
    vf 6 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off
    vf 7 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off
    vf 8 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off
    vf 9 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off
    vf 10 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking on, link-state auto, trust off
    vf 11 MAC fa:16:3e:19:8c:05, vlan 1929, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on
    vf 12 MAC fa:16:3e:43:88:4f, vlan 1927, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on
    vf 13 MAC fa:16:3e:4f:b3:d0, vlan 1925, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on
    vf 14 MAC fa:16:3e:56:b6:4a, vlan 1923, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on
    vf 15 MAC 02:f1:f1:04:01:03, vlan 1938, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on
```

you can do 1 to 1 mapping and identify which is the vf you are interested in. Assume its vf 15.

Step 3- go to dir /.

```
# cd 15/stats
```

Step 4 - do ls and cat all files , except tx_spoofed

```
ls -lrt
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan  9 21:40 tx_errors
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan  9 21:40 rx_packets
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan  9 21:40 tx_dropped
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan  9 21:40 tx_spoofed
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan  9 21:40 tx_packets
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan  9 21:40 rx_bytes
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan  9 21:40 rx_dropped
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan  9 21:40 tx_bytes

# tail  *
==> rx_bytes <==
108786154191

==> rx_dropped <==
0

==> rx_packets <==
975217621

==> tx_bytes <==
433665695588

==> tx_dropped <==
0

==> tx_errors <==
0

==> tx_packets <==
590997020
```

---

```
# tail  *
==> rx_bytes <==
108786397727

==> rx_dropped <==
0

==> rx_packets <==
975220967

==> tx_bytes <==
433665771018

==> tx_dropped <==
0

==> tx_errors <==
0

==> tx_packets <==
590998121
```

These are your counters.

BR//
Sanjeev Tewari

Answer (score 0):

You can see VF counters from the host with: `ip -s link show <pnic>`

For example, I do `ip -s link show ens1f0` and see this output corresponding with VF `22`:

```
vf 22     link/ether 56:b8:7a:ed:41:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, vlan 30, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on
    RX: bytes  packets  mcast   bcast   dropped 
         30540      206       4       3        0 
    TX: bytes  packets   dropped 
         29082      213        0
```

To get these values as JSON:

```json
ip -j -s link | jq '.[] | select(.ifname == "ens1f0") | .vfinfo_list[] | select(.vf==22)'
```